# Weird space between English text and parentheses in RTL environment

Tags: xetex, languages, right-to-left

I have a document with text in Hebrew, as well as some English text. Whenever I put the English text in parenthesis and process the document with XeTeX a space appears between the right bracket and the English text in the output.

Here's the MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,english,hebrew]{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\newfontfamily\hebrewfont[Script=Hebrew]{David CLM}
\newfontfamily\hebrewfonttt[Script=Hebrew]{Miriam Mono CLM}
\newfontfamily\hebrewfontsf[Script=Hebrew]{Simple CLM}

\usepackage{polyglossia}

\setdefaultlanguage{hebrew}
\setotherlanguage{english}

\begin{document}
טקסט כלשהו (\textenglish{abc}) עוד טקסט:
\end{document}
```

And the output:

[image: Redundant space between the bracket and "abc"]

If you put the brackets inside `\textenglish{}` the space between the preceding Hebrew word and the bracket is doubled:

[image: Redundant space between the Hebrew word and the bracket]

What might be causing this behavior?

Comment: I cannot reproduce your problem with TeXLive 2020 and version 0.133 of the Culmus fonts. Placing the parentheses inside and outside of `\textenglish{}` displays fine. (By the way, you don't need the `english,hebrew` global options.)

Comment: @DavidPurton - I'm using MiKTeX, but you can reproduce this problem in Overleaf.

Comment: So I see. Overleaf runs TeXLive 2019. Since you are using MikTeX, can you just update things? Make sure you update in both user and admin modes.

Comment: @DavidPurton - Thank you. Updating 100+ packages solved the problem.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the problem was solved by updating MikTeX